# New issue in converting python arrays

Tags: python, numpy, physics

So I have a file that looks like this, called xs80.txt:

```
0.0126619524  0.0  0.0  0.0122716055  0.0  0.0   0.0119240615  0.0  0.0
2.8980740435  0.0  0.0  2.9224417792  0.0  0.0   2.9449901605  0.0  0.0
0.1569375956  0.0  0.0  0.1546671493  0.0  0.0   0.1526119469  0.0  0.0

with open("xs80.txt", "r") as ins:
            array = []
            for line in ins:
              array.append(line)
    from numpy import loadtxt
    text_file = open("xs80.txt", "r")
    myarray = numpy.array(text_file.read().split(','))
```

So when I do this conversion I get the error message:

```
 ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I had thought that the dimensions 3,3,3 for reshaping the read in array to a 3d array would work since the file has 27 elements and so it could be placed into a 3 dimensional array with length 3, width 3 and vector size 3.  Am I still missing something?

Comment: Is this really what your code says? You open your "xs80.txt" file inside a `with` block that already opens it? You import `loadtxt` from `numpy` and then don't use it?

Comment: Why are you splitting on commas? There are no commas in `xs80.txt`.

Comment: Why didn't you use loadtxt? it seems like that should be what you use

Comment: Sorry, should have split the lines better, I was not actually opening a file within a block where another file was opened.  I was placing different lines in areas to experiment and forgot to separate them when i posted it.

Comment: Seeing this and your other questions, I really urge you to take a look at python courses, aimed at scientific users, like https://github.com/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures#online-read-only-versions for example.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

To read the data into an 3x3x3 `numpy.array`, use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) directly, as it already splits the lines and converts the arguments to numbers.

```
myarray = numpy.loadtxt("xs80.txt").reshape(3,3,3)
```

## Remarks

Your code does have several further problems, though:

- Indentation is all over the place, you use two spaces, four spaces, and the beginning of the `with`-block has too much indentation. When I run your code I actually get

  ```
  from numpy import loadtxt
                          ^
  IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
  ```
- You read the lines from the file into `array`, but you don't do anything with `array`
- You import `numpy.loadtxt` and do nothing with it, either
- You open the file again, and convert its contents to a 1-element 1d `numpy.array` which contains a string:

  ```
  array([ '0.0126619524  0.0  0.0  0.0122716055  0.0  0.0   0.0119240615  0.0  0.0\n2.8980740435  0.0  0.0  2.9224417792  0.0  0.0   2.9449901605  0.0  0.0\n0.1569375956  0.0  0.0  0.1546671493  0.0  0.0   0.1526119469  0.0  0.0\n'], dtype='|S216')
  ```

  Since `text_file.read().split(',')` reads the whole file, including newlines, you end up with one large string containing all the characters in the file. You then split the string at the (non-existent) `','`, which returns the string itself.